# How can duplicate Shape and keep format setting?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table put in a Shape:

I want copy this shape and keep format of Table.

This is my code:

```
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim oTable2  As Object
Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oApp.Visible = True
Set oDocument = oApp.Documents.Open("E:\2022\t3.docx")
Set oTable2 = oDocument.Shapes(1).Duplicate
```

But table after duplicate , auto change font size

Result:

[image]

How can duplicate Shape and keep format setting of Table?

Comment: What is the point of putting the table in a Shape instead of applying text wrapping to the table itself?

Comment: There's a mismatch between your local font formatting of the table and your style setting for the text style used in the table. When you paste, the text reverts to the size specced in the style. You should be able to fix this by setting the Normal style of the Normal.dotm template to the text size you want the table to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fixed by using 2 Functions `copy & paste` of `Selection`

```
oDocument.Shapes(1).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Paste
```